# How to remove styles from previously clicked elements?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to apply style to only one radio button. The one that I clicked last.

I have multiple div with class="sizes" as below:

```
<div class="sizes">
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <div class="size" data-children-count="1">
        <input type="radio" name="size-button" class="size" id="PP" value="PP">
        <label class="size-label" for="PP">
            <!---->PP
            <!----></label>
    </div>
    <!---->
    <div class="size" data-children-count="1">
        <input type="radio" name="size-button" class="size" id="P" value="P">
        <label class="size-label" for="P">
            <!---->P
            <!----></label>
    </div>
    <!---->
    <div class="size" data-children-count="1">
        <input type="radio" name="size-button" class="size" id="M" value="M">
        <label class="size-label" for="M">
            <!---->M
            <!----></label>
    </div>
    <!---->
    <div class="size" data-children-count="1">
        <input type="radio" name="size-button" class="size" id="G" value="G">
        <label class="size-label" for="G">
            <!---->G
            <!----></label>
    </div>
    <!---->
    <div class="size" data-children-count="1" style="background: red;">
        <input type="radio" name="size-button" class="size" id="GG" value="GG">
        <label class="size-label" for="GG">
            <!---->GG
            <!----></label>
    </div>
    <!---->
</div>
```

I am applying background color to the clicked button via
`event.target.parentNode.style.background = "red";`

Now if I click another button, background color would apply there as well. I can remove style from all elements using s for loop like below, but is does not seem an effective way. How can I do this effectively?

```
const allSizeElements = document.querySelectorAll(".size");
for (let i = 0; i < allSizeElements.length; i++ ) {
  allSizeElements[i].style.background = "none";
}
```

I thought about doing this using only css, but I don't know how to target parent selector of following;

```
[type='radio']:checked
    background: red
```

Comment: Should consider toggling classes that have css rules instead. Easier to unwind

Comment: Yep, and then you can query by your "red" class to reduce the elements you need to loop over.

Comment: Yes, you need JavaScript but you don't need to modify styles directly. Add CSS classnames to active elements. A simple technique is to remove `.actve` from all `.size` elements and then add it to the one being clicked

Comment: And is more declarative in code to be able to read intent

Answer (score 1):

Use specific class for your checked state .I used as `.checked` class name. Then do following step...

- First you need to set click listener for all your radio elements.
- Inside click listener , remove `.checked` class from previous clicked radio element before added into current clicked element

```js
const allSizeElements = document.querySelectorAll(".size input");
for (let i = 0; i < allSizeElements.length; i++ ) {
  allSizeElements[i].addEventListener('click',function(event) {
    var prevRadio = document.querySelector('.checked');
    if(prevRadio) prevRadio.classList.remove('checked');
    event.target.parentNode.classList.add("checked"); 
   });
}
```

```css
.checked {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="sizes">
    <!---->
    <!---->
    <div class="size" data-children-count="1">
        <input type="radio" name="size-button" class="size" id="PP" value="PP">
        <label class="size-label" for="PP">
            <!---->PP
            <!----></label>
    </div>
    <!---->
    <div class="size" data-children-count="1">
        <input type="radio" name="size-button" class="size" id="P" value="P">
        <label class="size-label" for="P">
            <!---->P
            <!----></label>
    </div>
    <!---->
    <div class="size" data-children-count="1">
        <input type="radio" name="size-button" class="size" id="M" value="M">
        <label class="size-label" for="M">
            <!---->M
            <!----></label>
    </div>
    <!---->
    <div class="size" data-children-count="1">
        <input type="radio" name="size-button" class="size" id="G" value="G">
        <label class="size-label" for="G">
            <!---->G
            <!----></label>
    </div>
    <!---->
    <div class="size" data-children-count="1">
        <input type="radio" name="size-button" class="size" id="GG" value="GG">
        <label class="size-label" for="GG">
            <!---->GG
            <!----></label>
    </div>
    <!---->
</div>
```